# NATing with a single-homed machine possible?

Tags: networking, nat, iptables

I have the following setup:

a) a single-homed machine, A, that can see the Internet.

b) other machines B, C, and D that cannot see the Internet.

c) A, B, C, and D can see each other.

d) all machines are running either RHEL 5.3 or Fedora 16.

**Question:** Is it possible to have B, C, and D share the Internet connection with A somehow? Note, again, that machine A does not have a second NIC installed. *(The solutions that I am finding on the Net assume A to be a dual-homed system!)*

Also, could you please recommend a set of book(s) or online resources for a current and in-depth coverage of `iptables` for people with only a basic knowledge of TCP/IP?

Comment: How does A see the Internet if it's single-homed? How do B, C, and D get assigned IP addresses?

Comment: Well, A is itself using NAT: A's IP address is a private/internal IP address `192.168.x.y`. Using an `iptables` technique not known to me, our Sys Admin has allowed Internet to be accessible from A. But he is not allowing Internet accessibility on B, C, and D for some really childish 'reasons' (I believe, his intention is usually to make my life difficult). Now, just like 2 or more virtualbox based VMs can see Internet via their host OS, I would like B, C, and D (which are real machines) to be able to reach the Internet via A. All machines have DHCP-assigned private IP addresses.

Comment: Is this a decision the sys admin has the authority to make?

Comment: Yes. Such decisions are completely at his whim.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies within your router's capability.

You could use a DMZ for computer A and then firewall off all internet access to B,C,D - however A would not be accessible from b,c,d - it would be totally separate - and a DMZ will make computer A more visible to the internet than before.

Comment: I vaguely recall picking up some chatter on `iptables`'s ability to copy packets, 'NAT them', and then send them out via the same NIC... all without requiring a second NIC. Anything possible along these lines? Also, I'm wondering how do virtual machines (which would be B, C, and D) running on a host OS (which would be A, in the setup of this problem) accomplish this without requiring a second NIC.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about that sort of thing and I don't want to spread misinformation.  IPv6 is here (sorta) and will have an effect on the way things operate behind routers.  That's where I would start my search at.

Comment: IPv6 is not an issue right now.

Comment: I mention IPv6 because I think it could solve your issue.

Comment: Could you elaborate just a little bit more on **how** IPv6 could solve my issue?